# How to recover a deleted book in iBooks?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, books, data-recovery, epub

I deleted accidentally a book that I was reading and it already automagically synced to my iPhone as well.

It was a downloaded ePub. I added notes and bookmarks there.

Now that's gone. Is there any hope to get it back somehow?

I don't see anything like *Recently deleted* in iBooks.

Maybe we can get it from some kind of iPhone backups? In that case, I don't think my recent notes will be still there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happily, it seems that by readding the eBook file in the iBooks, the notes and bookmarks are back.

I had to redownload the eBook and open it in iBooks.

Answer (score 0):

Any deleted book will automatically be added to your Recently Deleted bookshelf and can be retrieved for 2 weeks (after which it will be permanently deleted and you can't find it there).

[image]

Luckily, iBooks saves your bookmarks, notes, and current page information with your Apple ID account, so they’re always up to date and you can read a book seamlessly across multiple iOS devices.

Just check the book on other devices or re-download it to see if the notes and bookmarks sync back.

Comment: Where is the *Recently Deleted* bookshelf?

Comment: Tap All Books > Recently Deleted > tap the + icon to restore a book.

Comment: Unfortunately, you just copied a snipped and an image from [this page](http://support.redjumper.net/hc/en-us/articles/201908131-How-to-retrieve-a-deleted-book). They talk about their app there, not about iBooks.